# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty (rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following the rails blog tutorial (you know, *that one* ) and i've come to a point where every time i reference @articles on the update form, rails takes it as a nil, it says:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Here's the form

```
<h1>Edit article</h1>

<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

And the controller for the articles:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create   
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if  @article.save
    redirect_to @article
    else
    render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like you have an edit method in your Articles controller.

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Just so it is clear.  The edit method is what is called with the *GET* route that shows the form.  Update is the *PATCH/PUT* route that takes the form in and updates the record.  So, the form is **shown** by the **edit** method via *GET*, and **processed** by the **update** method via *PUT/PATCH*.

Comment: Worked like a charm, don't know why i thought it'd work without an _edit_ method, thanks!